Apollo GraphQL, trigger client query refetching from server after mutation from another device
I have a react native app using React Apollo Client on the frontend and React Apollo Server on the backend. The point of the app is for users to collaborate in building an inventory of items.
My problem is that currently users needs to blindly refresh to pull new data inserted by other users.
i.e : When John add a new Chair to the inventory, then Maria don't see the Chair until she refresh.
To solve this I've consider the following solutions, and I'd like to have your opinions about which one (or another one) would be the best in the context of Apollo GraphQL.

Interval polling : Refresh the inventory data every X seconds. Very easy to setup but I'm not so confortable with the idea of generating a very large number of requests for most of the time nothing.
Server Sent Events : Open a stream and push notification to clients so they can refresh their data. But it seems to me that it would require implementing a solution on the side of Apollo
Apollo Subscription : I've seen that Apollo GraphQL propose subscriptions, but they don't seems specially fit for my use case. I'm wondering what would be the best way to adapt them for refreshing caches ? And what are the benefits of using the Web services implementation or the HTTP Multipart implementation ?

Thank you for your opinions.

Salut Ola, ça roule? Subscriptions are the "standard" way to go with GraphQL however recognize that this requires websocket support in your infra. Also subscriptions used to be not awesome in Apollo but they have apparently gotten a lot better recently. You might look at AWS Amplify on the server side as well since it has strong subscription support. btw, be aware your question might get closed as it's architectural rather than about coding.

Hi Michel ! Nice to hear from you :) Thanks for your feedback. Any opinion regarding the usage of HTTP multipart vs WS ? Yes I know it’s quite architectural, but I always feel like spreading myself when posting on other stacks ^^

No opinion on that, haven't tried multipart.
